# How to Generate bulk QR/bar code in flutter and save the generated code as PDF?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a QR/Bar code Generator app in which users are allowed to give the quantity(also some name printed below the bar code) they want to generate and save the generated code as a PDF. What is the best way to generate bulk QR/Bar codes in flutter?

With the below code I am able to generate one QR/Bar code

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [

        SfBarcodeGenerator(
          barColor: Colors.white,
          value: controller.text,
          //symbology: QRCode(),
          showValue: true,
          textSpacing: 15,
          textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.red),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 40),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: buildTextField(context)),
            const SizedBox(width: 12),
            FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Icon(Icons.done, size: 30),
              onPressed: () {
                print("I am from on Pressed");
                Expanded(child: resultTextField(context,controller.text));
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Any help is really appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [qr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter) plugin.

Comment: I have used the qr_flutter plugin as well something like this -> QrImage(data: "Bar1001"). I am able to generate one single QR code. I indeed get the quantity (input from the user upon clicking Generate QR) and generate a bulk QR code(let's say 100,200,300,400.....). How can I do it using the plugin?